# Spring Data Rest: Target bean is not of type of the persistent entity

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have a data model called `Project` which is lifecycled from an Angular app via Spring Data Rest. The `Project` has `Scene`s, Scenes have `UpstreamKey`s held in a `Map<Integer, UpstreamKey>` and `UpstreamKey` is an abstract class with two implementations `ChromaKey` and `LumaKey`. (see code below)

When I edit (`PUT`) and existing `Project` with a `ChromaKey` in the map, and change that to a `LumaKey`, I get an error message in the backend:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target bean of type io.mewald.notime.designer.model.scene.usk.LumaKey is not of type of the persistent entity (io.mewald.notime.designer.model.scene.usk.chroma.ChromaKey)!: io.mewald.notime.designer.model.scene.usk.LumaKey
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.instanceCheckFailed(Assert.java:702) ~[spring-core-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:621) ~[spring-core-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.verifyBeanType(BasicPersistentEntity.java:584) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.getPropertyAccessor(BasicPersistentEntity.java:458) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader$MergingPropertyHandler.<init>(DomainObjectReader.java:639) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.lambda$mergeForPut$1(DomainObjectReader.java:141) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.mergeForPut(DomainObjectReader.java:139) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.lambda$mergeMaps$6(DomainObjectReader.java:429) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.mergeMaps(DomainObjectReader.java:418) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.access$000(DomainObjectReader.java:65) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader$MergingPropertyHandler.doWithPersistentProperty(DomainObjectReader.java:673) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:374) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.lambda$mergeForPut$1(DomainObjectReader.java:143) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.mergeForPut(DomainObjectReader.java:139) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.lambda$mergeCollections$7(DomainObjectReader.java:469) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.mergeCollections(DomainObjectReader.java:452) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.access$100(DomainObjectReader.java:65) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader$MergingPropertyHandler.doWithPersistentProperty(DomainObjectReader.java:675) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:374) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.lambda$mergeForPut$1(DomainObjectReader.java:143) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.mergeForPut(DomainObjectReader.java:139) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.readPut(DomainObjectReader.java:116) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.JsonPatchHandler.applyPut(JsonPatchHandler.java:100) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.readPutForUpdate(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:234) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
    ... 90 common frames omitted
```

My interpretation is that it is somehow trying to merge the `LumaKey` into the `ChromaKey` and - of course - that doesn't work. Why is it not simply replacing the bean? What would be a fix to get this working?

Here's the structure of the data model relevant to this questions:

```
@NoArgsConstructor @Data @SuperBuilder @AllArgsConstructor
@Document
public class Project {
    @Id
    private String id;
    ...
    private List<Scene> scenes;
}

@NoArgsConstructor @Data @SuperBuilder @AllArgsConstructor @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class Scene {
    ...
    private Map<Integer, UpstreamKey> upstreamKeys;
}

@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor @SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ChromaKey.class, name = "ChromaKey"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LumaKey.class, name = "LumaKey")
})
public abstract class UpstreamKey {
    ...
    public abstract String getType();
}

@Data @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true) @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor @SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class ChromaKey extends UpstreamKey {
    ...
    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "ChromaKey";
    }
}

@Data @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true) @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor @SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class LumaKey extends UpstreamKey {
    ...
    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "LumaKey";
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Taken from the documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.item-resource

```
The PUT method replaces the state of the target resource with the supplied request body.
```

The documentation explicitly talks about `replace` so I am wondering why a method called `mergeForPut` is involved at all.

**EDIT**: Just realised my `spring-boot-starter-parent` was a bit old. I updated to `2.6.4` but the error remains.

**EDIT**: I just refactored everything so that `scene.upstreamKeys` can be a `List` instead of a `Map` just in case this might cause it. But it does not. Still the same error.

**EDIT**: As requested, I created a minimum project that replicates the error I am describing above: https://github.com/mathias-ewald/demo-sdr-target-bean-is-not-of-type

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm experiencing the same issue, and I see what is happening, just haven't figured out how to fix it yet. What is happening, is when you save one of these jackson subtypes, they are saved with a field called "_class" that specifies the class it came from. So when you have an array of these subtypes, and call an update, it goes through each element in the array and tries to "merge" the new values in. If types of objects it is trying to merge into the existing document is in a different order, it tries to merge one object type into another and fails

Comment: No progress, unfortunately.

Comment: I had the same error message before and fixed, but I don't remember what I did. If you upload a minimum ready-to-run application to github, I can give it a try. Here is an [example application](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/spring-data-rest-projection). It uses in-memory H2 database and a [test case](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/spring-data-rest-projection/blob/without-address-repos/src/test/java/com/example/springdatarestprojection/SpringDataRestProjectionApplicationTests.java) to demo the request.

Comment: @yejianfengblue I created that demo application you requested at https://github.com/mathias-ewald/demo-sdr-target-bean-is-not-of-type

Comment: @yejianfengblue did you have a chance to look at it?

Comment: @user3235738 yes. Trying and making some test

Comment: @user3235738 I think my problem is not exactly the same as yours. I will still look at it

Comment: I edit my old answer which is deleted (hided) because I realized I misunderstand your original question. So comment to notify you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I can achieve the update in spring data mongodb, it's not possible in spring data rest now. In current spring data rest implementation, a PUT request try to merge the nested collection member by calling `DomainObjectReader.mergeForPut(...)` which fails on type mismatch, rather than replace it. See this github [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues/1374) and [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/pull/368).

So the workaround is implement a controller yourself.

## Edit 2022-04-05

Annotate `UpstreamKey` with `@Immutable` make spring data rest perform replacement rather than merge. This solution only works if the nested collection member is just value (no id, no audit data, no @JsonIgnore to hide server side data) instead of entity (with id).

Find the [updated project](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/demo-sdr-target-bean-is-not-of-type) and the [diff](https://github.com/mathias-ewald/demo-sdr-target-bean-is-not-of-type/compare/main...yejianfengblue:main)

Below is result mongo data after the put opertaion.

```json
{
    _id: ObjectId('624b9fe3f32185579ff56849'),
    name: 'Project 1',
    scenes: [
        {
            name: 'Scene 1',
            usks: [
                {
                    c: 3,
                    a: 1,
                    _class: 'com.example.demo.LumaKey'
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    _class: 'com.example.demo.Project'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortly you want to do type casting between LumaKey and ChromaKey. So it's not ok with Java.

You can check this answer. I debug your code and this is what you want.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004028/8909313

**Edit 1**
You try to delete ChromaKey and add LumaKey.

**Edit 2**

Please debug this
PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java (line 158 [readPutForUpdate method])

In this method request json and mongo json deserialize. And Object Mapper map them.

When mongodb object's usks field's type is ChromaKey but your request's type LumaKey.

And then spring call mapper method for mapping.

```
mapper.readerFor(target.getClass()).readValue(source);
```

for this line target's type is ChromaKey but source's type is LumaKey.

So mapper cannot cast your ChromaKey to LumaKey.

I try to write custom JsonDeserializer but it didn't solve your problem. Maybe you can try this way.

I think it's a logical problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch your proposed solution.